# RewriteRule for subfolder htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My url blog is here http://localhost/tibiaservers_11.10.19/blog

And my posts should be working like the following. after blog/

http://localhost/tibiaservers_11.10.19/blog/marketing-tools
http://localhost/tibiaservers_11.10.19/blog/the-cyber-house-rules

why isn't it working?

here is htaccess

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks






RewriteEngine On

# FOR LOCALHOST RewriteBase /tibiaservers_11.10.19/
# FOR PRODUCTION RewriteBase /

RewriteBase /tibiaservers_11.10.19/ 

DirectoryIndex index.php

# przekierowanie na bez www

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tibiaservers\.net$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/tibiaservers\.net\/" [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>



# For Blog

RewriteRule ^blog/t-(.*)$ tagpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

##### - blog end
```

Comment: _“here is htaccess”_ - yeah, but _where_ is it? Which _folder_ is it in?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `RewriteRule` should start with: `^tibiaservers_11.10.19/`

This:

```
RewriteRule ^tibiaservers_11.10.19/blog/t\-(.*)$ tagpost.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Would match this url:

```
http://localhost/tibiaservers_11.10.19/blog/t-asdf
```

I use this tool for testing my .htaccess rules: [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=ff062c2a-15f8-596f-a12b-7653ae976bf7)

Comment: still not working error 404. Need I /tibiaservers_11.10.19/  in rewrite rule if RewriteBase has /tibiaservers_11.10.19/ ??

Comment: Could you try to describe what you're doing rather than posting a video. It's hard to understand what is happening in that video.

Also when posting code please use the formatter to make it readable like I've done in my answer.